# Android Get Sim State

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print the sims state to screen. At the moment I cannot seem to get it to work.
What I want to be able to do is print if a sim card is locked or not.

I have been using this code

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int state = manager.getSimState();
    answer1.setText(state);
```

but the LogCat output is

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.q.m/com.q.m.Q}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at com.q.m.Q.onCreate(Q.java:77)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(213):     ... 11 more

Line 77 is the

> TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)

Line

Comment: Is that the line that causes the trouble? I copied the first two lines into a sample app, logged the 'state' value, ran it, and it caused no exception.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste your java file into an answer. If I can get it to run then i will accept that as the answer. Cheers for the help.

Comment: `getSystemService` is not a static method you should drop the Context in Context.getSystemService see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing an int to a function that expects a string.

Replace

`answer1.setText(state);`

with

`answer1.setText(Integer.toString(state));`

Comment: If that were the issue it shouldn't compile

Comment: It may compile, as some views like a `TextView` on the android can take an integer parameter (a resource ID) that points to a particular string. However, the parameter passed was not a resource ID, and probably caused the error when the string was going to be retrieved from resources (where it didn't exist).

Comment: If that were the case it would have unexpected results but wouldn't throw a NullPointerException

Answer (score -1):

You should check if you've set the permission READ_PHONE_STATE in your Manifest file, and also by calling

```
    answer.setText(state)
```

you are calling TextView's

```
    setText(int resId)
```

method, which is looking for a text Resource with the supplied id.